# Mongo _Audit Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Usually in RDBMS we will have _Audit table for every table. 
For example.. 
table:Login 
columns: username, password, lastlogin,preference1,preference2 etc.

table: Login_Audit will have the values before got modified. This will have history of all the changes and will get purged once in 2 weeks or month. Usually the _Audit table entry will be made by triggers. 
columns: username, password, lastlogin,preference1,preference2 etc., modifiedby, modifiedtime

**Just like _audit table in Rdbms, how to maintain 
who create the document, 
LastmodifiedUser, lastmodifiedtime.. etc. 
It should be fine if i can able to maintain these information in same collection itself.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB, at present (2.6), doesn't have any auditing features. There are [auditing features](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/auditing/) in MongoDB Enterprise (i.e. these features aren't free). The auditing system tracks events like the following, on a per connection/user basis:

- authentication
- creating and dropping collections
- creating and dropping indexes
- creating and deleting users
- creating, deleting, modifying, and granting roles
- replica set reconfiguration
- sharding administration actions
- server shutdowns